# We can go for transaction management in procedure but we can’t go in function?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

**We can go for transaction management in procedure but we can’t go in function**, I have seen this statement at multiple places, while we ask for difference between function & procedure, But I did below test in ***oracle*** and `**I can see its working fine for function also**`. Can anybody please let me know what thing am I missing about above statement, because this statement looks completely wrong to me?

`select * from test;` *(test table having single column "**name varchar(2)**")

```
create or replace function FUNTest
return number as result NUMBER(6,2);
BEGIN 
SAVEPOINT fn_fntest;
insert into test(NAME) values('Dinesh');
ROLLBACK TO fn_fntest;
return 1;
END;
/

Begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FUNTest());
end;
/
```

Comment: @MitchWheat, In Oracle, (I mentioned in the description let me highlight that part) Well doesn't transaction work withing function in sql like it's working in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of function is different from procedure.

1. Function: Supposed to do some calculation and return some value(most
   of the cases)
2. Procedure: Perform some operation based on data/column.It manages transaction as well, because you will definately be storing new data somewhere.

Now talking about transaction management in function, well it depends on calling mechanism of function.

If your function is having transactional statement like commit/rollback then it should be called from some other block which is capable of handling transaction like procedure or anonymous block(your case).

If you call that same function from select statement like "**select funtest() from dual;**" then you will get error as select statement is not capable of opening transaction.

If you still want to call any function having transactional statement from non-transactional body(select statement) then your function should be capable of opening separate independent transaction(PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION).

Please refer to http://www.datacoons.com/content/transaction.php for more information on transaction management.